# Convergence in infinite dimensional Euclidian space

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have a question regarding proving statements for infinite-dimensional Euclidean spaces.

Suppose for each $T \in \mathbb{N}$ I have sequence of $\mathbf{x}_T = (x_{T,i})^T_{i=1}$. And suppose I have one sequence $(y_i)^{\infty}_{i=1}$. I know that for each $n < \infty$ when $T \to \infty$ vector $\mathbf{x}_T[:n]$ converges to "static" vector $y[:n]$ (this converges could be treated as convergence in $||.||_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ and $y[:n]$ denotes first $n$ elements of sequence).

I want to prove that $\sum^T_{i=1} |x_{T, i} - y_i| \to 0$ when $T \to \infty$.

I have no idea what methods could be used to jump to $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ here. Because number of summands in the statement in growing, when $T \to \infty$.

Thank you!